# Offlineimap error: ImportError: cannot import name OfflineImap

Tags: python, imap

In trying to use offlineimap under Linux, I am now getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/offlineimap", line 20, in <module>
    from offlineimap import OfflineImap
ImportError: cannot import name OfflineImap
```

No matter what I do. I wasn't originally getting this error, but I've tried purging and reinstalling offlineimap (and deleting .offlineimap) and it doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, first thing first: does it work from the interactive python interpreter?
Are you using virtualenv? Maybe you have offlineimap installed in a virtualenv and are trying to call it globally.

At last, I would check if the offlineimap.py file defines the OfflineImap class (or module?)

Comment: Well, I looked at the offlineimap file itself (which resides in /usr/bin ). It simply marks itself as a Python file, has copyright info, and then 3 lines: (1) from offlineimap import OfflineImap, (2) oi = OfflineImap(), (3) oi.run(). If I try the first one in the Python interpreter, I get the same error as above. So I'm thinking there's a file/files missing somewhere, or else the /usr/bin/offlineimap file itself is somehow messed up. (But, again, purging and reinstalling doesn't seem to help....)

Comment: Ok, I've got it working now. The (apparent?!) fix was to install offlineimap from the git repository. (I think this simply restored whatever file was missing; still dunno why apt-get couldn't do the same....)